What can be used as "non-physical" electrodes?
Well, I hope physics is the right place for this and not worldbuilding.

I was watching some stuff and I'm curious about the possibility of energy shields in real life.
https://youtu.be/VK2nh88m6t0
Basically, there is a type of tank armor called "electric armor". The armor consists of two separate electrodes (two conductive plates), when a projectile penetrates both plates, a short circuit is created across it, vaporizing the projectile.
The only problem with this type of armor is that eventually it will turn into a swiss cheese with so many holes, no longer protecting the target.
The solution would be "non-physical" electrodes, energy bubbles that would work as if they were the electrodes.
But I can't think of anything that could work (at least within the Earth's atmosphere).
The closest I could think of would be to keep conductive plastic spheres and/or unpoppable soap bubbles floating around the target using sound waves.
https://youtu.be/fk5I62PPMH4
https://youtu.be/Dj1V6SSLIj8
But I don't know if these ideas would even work, and if they did, would they be practical.

Not sure what you mean by non-physical as all those things are still matter/physical material. But electric current can flow through any number of materials provided the potential difference is large enough.

I’m not sure what utility this armor (electric armor) has. Congratulations, you have just turned the solid one-kilo slug moving towards you into a one-kilo jet of molten metal moving towards you. “Vaporizing” the projectile wouldn’t be very helpful either (congratulations, you just turned a regular bullet into a plasma bolt) and effectively using it would take an amount of energy throughput that would certainly be unsafe to store in something as small as a tank. Besides, all the enemy has to do is use a size of bullet that doesn’t bridge the gap, or just use something like FPV drones instead of bullets.
Anyway the physics of this electric armor is also way out of wack. Resistive heating is given by $P=I^2R$ for power dissipated due to heat $P$, current $I$, and resistance $R$. Assuming a one-kilo tungsten slug with heat capacity of about 0.134 joules per gram-Kelvin, it would take around 700,000 joules of energy to cause the slug to boil (a low estimate based on the energy required to bring it from roughly room-temperature to boiling and then assuming that the slug being fired added some heat to it). The resistivity of tungsten is aroud $5.8\times10^{-8}\,\Omega\,\mathrm{m}^{-1}$, and assuming a slug width of 1 cm (very generous), we get a resistance of $R= 0.0000058$. Then, $P= 0.0000058I^2$.
If the slug is moving at a kilometer per second (very generous estimate), and the electric armor is fifty centimeters thick (very generous estimate), and the slug enters at a perfect angle so its uniform heating starts the moment it enters the cavity in the armor and stops the moment it hits the tank (‘cause you know, at that point the armor has failed), then it’ll be heated for around half a millisecond. Since $P=\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and we know that $\mathrm{d}E\approx700\,000$ to boil the slug, we realize that $P\approx350\,000\,000= 0.0000058I^2$. So, $I=\sqrt{\frac{350\,000\,000}{0.0000058}}\approx6.034\times10^{13}$. (In reality this would need to be higher for the voltage to be great enough to break down the air between the anodes and the cathodes and get through to the slug, but I feel very generous today.)
Needless to say, generating sixty trillion watts inside an armored vehicle will have detrimental effects on its occupants (like death). Keep in mind that that’s several kilotons of TNT per second; one kilotons of TNT per second is approximately 4.1 terawatts.
You may say that we only actually need to generate that power for half a millisecond, and the total energy expenditure should be as low as 700,000 joules (which for the record is on par with the energy of the projectile; you might as well just use reactive armor at that point), but keep in mind that in battle you don’t know when you need to have the armor on. If you’re already aware exactly when the bullet is going to arrive, then sure, but if you know that, you’re certainly not in an actual combat situation.

One can imagine a working scenario. Assume you are protecting against RPG's which use an explosive to propel a jet after making contact with the tank armor. A screen of a conducting mesh or layers of a conductor could heat the shell enough to ignite the primer and explode the RPG before it reaches the armor. The power source and conductors heavy enough to not melt or vanish in arcs while delivering power like a hydroelectric dam are a different problem.

And you're sure that the now-ignited primer wouldn't cause damage in the form of a detonation premature by less than a meter, projecting a jet of molten metal and a shockwave onto the tank?

For sure, but the RPG is designed fire the shaped charge after the thin nose has collapsed and the copper slug is the optimal distance from the the armor. A few centimeters I think.

If we are bound to stay within Maxwell's equations (at least here in Physics SE), then I have no good news for you. For such an armor you need a gradient of potential, and the source of electric potential is electric charge. Then Earnshaw's theorem states that you cannot have a stable configuration of charges separated in space by purely electrical forces (no quantum physics).
On the other hand "if can't beat them, join them". If your armor is inevitably going to become a Swiss cheese, then build it as such from beginning. Make an armor of two parallel sparse meshes (such that projectiles will most likely fly in between the mesh rods) and apply you voltage difference between them. There is nothing wrong with your electrons not being solid. Of course, given how many volts you'll need, you still have a problem with air breakdown. But then you'd have it anyway which the original solid armor even with a single hole, of with immaterial electrodes, provided they let air molecules through (why wouldn't they)? But you can put this armor on a spacecraft instead! Won't they live in space but that time anyway?
